# matriz en en forma de tabla y suma de diagonal

Tags: c++

Quiero que los datos que ingreso en una matriz de 4 filas y 5 columnas se visualicen ordenadamente al momento de imprimir,solo he colocado un salto de linea y un tabulador para hacer que se vea un poco ordenado,pero quisiera que los números estuvieran separados entre si y acercarse mejor a la visualización de una tabla,ademas quisiera saber como se puede sumar ambas diagonales de la matriz: diagonal principal y diagonal secundaria.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    using namespace std;

    int main(){
    int fila,columna,matriz[4][5];

   for(fila=0;fila<4;fila++){
    cout<<"\n\n";
    for(columna=0;columna<5;columna++){
        cout<<"Ingrese numero para la posicion"<<" "<<fila<<" "<<columna<<":";
        cin>>matriz[fila][columna];
    }
}
cout<<"\n\n";
system("pause");
    for(fila=0;fila<4;fila++){
        cout<<"\n";
        cout<<"\t";
    for(columna=0;columna<5;columna++){
        cout<<matriz[fila][columna];

}
}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para sumar las diagonales de una matriz hay una condición:

> La **matriz** debe ser una [Matriz Cuadrada](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matriz_cuadrada), esto quiere decir que tanto el numero de filas como el numero de columnas deben ser iguales, ya que solo asi, los valores son tomados como valores diagonales. De lo contrario, no se podra ejecutar la operacion de sumar las diagonales.

Basta con hacer una simple [prueba de escritorio](http://hustariz.cs.umss.edu.bo/algPruEscr.htm). Esto no es mas que visualizar la matriz que vas a crear como un arreglo de posiciones y evaluar que condiciones necesitas.

Para sumar la primera diagonal, basta con darse cuenta que cada indice del numero en la diagonal de la fila, es igual al indice de la columna. Por consiguiente, sumar la diagonal simplemente necesitas un **for que avance la fila y la columna al mismo tiempo** se procede a sumar el valor almacenado en esas posiciones de la matriz.

Para la segunda diagonal, es un poco diferente. Aqui te das cuenta que cada numero esta en el indice limite tanto de la fila, como de la columna respectivamente. Por lo que tendrias que recorrer un ciclo, donde el indice de la fila comience al final de la fila y no en cero y el indice de la columna en cero. Esto provocara que recorra los valores de la seguna diagonal en un solo ciclo. En este caso simplemente necesitas un **for que avance los valores al mismo tiempo, pero ambos en sentido contrario, comenzando la fila al final y la columna al principio (de manera reversada)**.

Moldeando un poco tu código quedaría así:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

const int filas = 4;
const int columnas = 4;


int SumarPrimeraDiagonal(int matriz[filas][columnas]){
    int sumaDiagonal = 0;
    for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < filas && j < columnas; i++, j++)
       sumaDiagonal += matriz[i][j];

    // Otra forma alternativa, como filas = columnas para poder sumar
    /* 
      for(int i = 0; i < filas; i++)
         sumaDiagonal += matriz[i][i];
    */
    return sumaDiagonal;       
}

int SumarSegundaDiagonal(int matriz[filas][columnas]){ 
    int sumaDiagonal = 0;
    for(int i = filas - 1, j = 0; i >= 0 && j < columnas; i--, j++)
        sumaDiagonal += matriz[i][j];

    return sumaDiagonal;
}

int main(){

    int matriz[filas][columnas];

    for(int i = 0; i < filas; i++){
        cout<<"\n\n";
        for(int j = 0;  j < columnas;  j++){
            cout << "Ingrese numero para la posicion" << "[" << i << ", " << j << "]:";
            cin >> matriz[i][j];
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
    cout << "\n\n";

    for(int i = 0; i < filas; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < columnas; j++){
            cout << matriz[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }

    cout << endl;
    if(filas != columnas)
        cout << "La matriz debe ser cuadrada para poder sumas sus diagonales" << endl;
    else{    
        int primeraDiagonal = SumarPrimeraDiagonal(matriz);
        int segundaDiagonal = SumarSegundaDiagonal(matriz);
        cout << "Suma de la primera diagonal: " << primeraDiagonal << endl;
        cout << "Suma de la segunda diagonal: " << segundaDiagonal  << endl;
        cout << "Suma de ambas diagonales: " << primeraDiagonal + segundaDiagonal << endl; 
    }

}
```

**PD:** ten en cuenta que definí las variables filas y columnas como constantes porque en tu código las definías de manera constante por igual, esto con el fin de poder pasar el arreglo bidimensional sin problemas, hay muchas alternativas, pero decidí crear variables constantes globales. Si en dado caso quieres asignar filas y columnas de manera dinamica (leyendo los valores) y no tienes mucho conocimiento en programación, puedes pasar el codigo de los métodos `SumarPrimeraDiagonal` y `SumarSegundaDiagonal` al final del `main()` y las variables constantes declararlas normal en el mismo. Te funcionara sin problemas.

Para probar matrices de otros tamaños, cambia el numero de filas y columnas constante:

```
const int filas = #Numero que quieras de filas;
const int columnas = #Numero que quieras de columnas;
```

Comment: Si la matriz debe ser cuadrada... ¿Por qué estableces las filas y las columnas con dos constantes diferentes? Sería más coherente tener una única constante llamada `tableSize` o similar para limitar ambas dimensiones a la vez

Comment: @eferion, lo que pasa es que hay mas casos, lo establecí asi porque el en su caso de prueba utilizó 2 variables de entrada. Si ese hubiera sido el caso lo haría asi y no me dedico a hacer la evaluación de si las filas es igual a las columnas. Simplemente le di la condición, no se si el estaba buscando trabajar solo con matrices cuadradas.

Comment: nada que objetar al respecto... solo me pareció raro hacer el paso a constantes y no unificar los valores